# Installation shinyProxy: file location

Tags: centos7, shinyproxy

(i’m using centOS 7)

I’m following this [tutorial](https://www.shinyproxy.io/getting-started/), I’m at the part Download ShinyProxy and i download [the rpm file](https://www.shinyproxy.io/downloads/). I install it with this command

```
$ sudo yum localinstall shinyproxy_2.3.0_x86_64.rpm
```

The folder **/etc/shinyproxy** is empty.

My question is where is the files **shinyproxy-2.3.0.jar**, **application.yml** ?

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution to this question?

Comment: hello, no i didn't.

Comment: If you want to use *shinyproxy-2.3.0.jar*, you don't need to install *shinyproxy_2.3.0_x86_64.rpm*.

Answer (score 0):

The `application.yml` that `shinyproxy` runs on will be located in `/etc/shinyproxy/application.yml`.

#### System info:

```
> Linux my_vm 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Dec 10 11:15:38 EST
> 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Make sure to run `systemctl stop shinyproxy`, followed by `systemctl start shinyproxy` to implement changes.